# Angular project crashes when I import MatDialogModule?

Tags: angular, typescript

My project works fine, but the moment I uncomment this line and save the project crashes

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

this is the error message

```
√ Compiled successfully.
⠋ Generating browser application bundles...C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40
                throw new Error("The target entry-point \"" + invalidTarget.entryPoint.name + "\" has missing dependencies:\n" +
                ^

Error: The target entry-point "@angular/material/dialog" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/cdk/overlay
 - @angular/cdk/portal
 - @angular/cdk/bidi
 - @angular/cdk/a11y
 - @angular/cdk/platform
 - @angular/cdk/keycodes

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.SingleProcessorExecutorBase.doExecute (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:28:29)
    at C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:59
    at SyncLocker.lock (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)   
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:175:16)
    at C:\Users\daees\Desktop\Ionic project\clicknex\clicknext\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:146:18
```

Comment: If you have all the required dependencies added in your package.json file, you could probably delete the node_modules folder and re-run a npm install. From the error, it seems there are some dependencies missing.

Comment: I suggest to try to import following way: `import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material';`
Did you add `MatDialogModule` to the `imports` array in your module configuration?

Answer (score 0):

There are following case's for the above error

1. Please verify angular material is install or not. If it is not install please run the below command
   npm i @angular/material
2. If already intsall please delete node_modules folder and run npm install again.